# MySQL Select distinct values from same cell

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a table with the following structure. The problem is i have to store multiple values in the "Functions" column. I know this practice should be avoided but i am searching for a solution on this scenario.

```
ID   Chapters   Functions
```

```
1    Chapter 1  Function 1
                Function 2
                Function 2

2    Chapter 2  Test 1
                Test 2
                Function 2
```

I am searching for a MySQL query that will output the following

```
Function 1
Function 2
Test 1
Test 2
```

I have tried the following query but it does not work of course since it treats the contents of each cell as a whole.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Functions from Chapters
```

I have also tried solving this problem in via PHP's *array_unique* function but it didn't work either.

Comment: How ypu are storing Functions column? Is it comma separated in same column? e.g 1 chapter1 Function1,Function2 ?

Comment: @Alex how the values are seperated in the column..is it by spaces or any other charachter?

Comment: Values are entered to database via a textarea, so when the user enters a function, presses the "Enter" key to switch line and enter the next function on a new line. Functions appear on new lines inside the DB when viewed from PhpMyAdmin. No special characters are stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the values are seperated by new line you can use `\n` escape sequences along with SUBSTRING_INDEX function and inner join you can achieve the same

Check below example

```
CREATE TABLE func (
  id INT,
  functions VARCHAR(200));

INSERT INTO func VALUES
(1, 'Function 1
     Function 2
     Function 2'),
(2, 'Test 1
     Test 2
     Function 2');
```

Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT

  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(func.functions, '\n', numbers.n), '\n', -1) as result 
FROM
  (SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2
   UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) numbers INNER JOIN func
  ON CHAR_LENGTH(func.functions)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(func.functions, '\n', ''))>=numbers.n-1
ORDER BY
  functions
```

Result

```
   result
Function 1
Function 2
Test 1
Test 2
```